# Renaming project of cordova 3.1 in xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-3

I can't change the cordova 3.1 project name in xcode. I try renaming as following like I did in previous version, but old name is coming in device. Please Help!
[image]

Comment: Have you try with changing `Product name`. in Build Setting.

Comment: Yes, but after renaming it, it appear red in xcode. But app name is still coming older.

Comment: You can change it in the config.xml file in your www folder. After that you have to build the app again.